# Creating a password user registration using make_password django

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords, pbkdf2

I'm trying to create a registration form where a user enter's in a username/password combination.

I want the password to use  `MyPBKDF2` for password hashing.

I have **hashers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import PBKDF2PasswordHasher

    class MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher(PBKDF2PasswordHasher):
        """
        A subclass of PBKDF2PasswordHasher that uses 100 times more iterations.
        """
        iterations = PBKDF2PasswordHasher.iterations * 100
```

**settings.py**

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'MyApp.hashers.MyPBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

**views.py**

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():

            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   #set clean username
            hashpass = make_password(RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass'], None, 'pbkdf2_sha256')

            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Newuser/?userNm=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='300')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'Myapp/reuse/register.html', {
            'RegForm': RegForm 
        })
```

**forms.py**
c

```
lass RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    userPass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Password')
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['userNm','userPass']


def clean_RegForm(self):
    cleanedUserName = self.cleaned_data.get('userNm')
    if Client.objects.filter(userNm=cleanedUserName).exists():
        errorMsg = u"Error occurred."
        raise ValidationError(errorMsg)
    else:
        return cleanedUserName
```

I'm getting the password submitting, but in plain text - which is no good.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show us RegistrationForm class please..

Comment: @mariodev - code updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. you're creating hashed password, but not saving it anywhere.
And because you're saving form (which inherits from ModelForm), the password fields is saved straight from the password form field.

You can override save method and set `hashpass` as password. But I think the best practice here is to use `UserCreationForm` which handles password hashing for you (it will use the first password hasher from your list).

There are some examples here on SO, showing how to customize UserCreationForm, so search around.

**Pseudo-code:**

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do not require password confirmation
        del self.fields['password2']
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    form = RegisterForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            # redirect!

    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Isn't this using forms instead of utilizing a modelform?

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty confused here. Can you give me a barebones example using my code above? I would really appreciate it